# Why Scala compiler couldn't infer a type of function from the context?

Tags: scala

I wonder why Scala compiler couldn't infer a type of my combiner function. Here is the code

```
object WordsCount extends App {

  import java.io.File
  import scala.io.Source.fromFile

  type CombinerType = (((String, Int), (String, Int)) => ((String, Int)))

  val src = fromFile(new File("/Users/finkel/test/src/main/resources/words.txt"))
  var mapped: Iterator[(String, Int)] = src getLines() flatMap { _.split(" ") } map { (_,1) }

  val combiner: CombinerType = {
    case ((a, b), (c, d)) => ("_", b + d)
  }

  val wordsAmount = mapped.reduce(combiner)._2
  println(wordsAmount)

}
```

As you can see I need to tell the compiler that the type of combiner is a function. If I don't do that compiler say

```
Error:(16, 18) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
  val combiner = {
                 ^
```

But I don't understand here one moment. Is it so hard to infer Combiner type?

Comment: Seems pretty hard, yeah ... Not sure what makes you think it''s easy. What type should `a` be and why? Or `b` for that matter ... Wait, maybe, I know where your confusion is. It doesn't know you are going to pass it to `reduce` when it is creating the `val`.

Comment: Yes, I can write it like this: `val wordsAmount =  src.getLines().flatMap(_.split(" ")).map((_, 1)).reduce({case ((a, b), (c, d)) => ("_", b + d)})._2` and get the same error.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know. But, you should have put this into your question. The way it is written, it's very obvious why it's not supposed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter has no idea what types `combiner` should expect and return (`a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` could be anything for all it knows), so you will need to explicitly specify the types, as all values are typed in scala.

To answer your other problem in the comments, the `reduce` method has type parameter `[A1 >: A]`, where `A` here is `(String, Int)`, and is the lower bound to the `reduce`'s result, thus the compiler has trouble inferring the actual type you desire.

Comment: the upper bound thing sounds promising... But then why does `List(1,2,3,4).reduce(_ + _)` work?

Comment: @Dima this is actually answered in Det's response. `_ + _` forms a "complete" function, as opposed to a partial function. For example, this would not compile: `List(1,2,3,4).reduce({case x : (Int, Int) => x._1 + x._2})`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using *case* inside your code block, you are forming a partial function, not a total one.

So for a partial function it is much more difficult for the compiler to infer the correct type of it from the context, or even impossible.

See http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html?m=1 for a nice explanation of partial functions.